# sp_configure is not found in Azure SQL Database?

Tags: r, sql-server, azure-sql-database, server-configuration

I need sp_configure for running R scripts in MS SQL. But whenever I am trying to run anything like '**EXECUTE sp_configure**' or '**exec sp_execute_external_script**', it says '**Could not find stored procedure 'sp_configure'.**' and '**'sp_execute_external_script' failed because it is not supported in the edition of this SQL Server instance 'A5DC0B2838AC'. See books online for more details on feature support in different SQL Server editions.**'

I even tried to create system stored procedure sp_config but was getting error at this line of the procedure "**EXEC %%ServerConfiguration( ConfigID = @confignum ).SetValue( Value = @configvalue )**" and the error is **Incorrect syntax near '%'**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sp_configure options and RECONFIGURE are not available on Azure SQL Database as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-transact-sql-information). Some options are available using ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION.

To run R scripts let me recommend you [Azure Machine Learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/execute-r-script) or create a SQL Server VM on Azure.

You can now run R scripts on Azure SQL Database Machine Learning as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-quickstart-r-create-script).